# Qual a diferença entre "de confiança" e "confiável"?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Se eu não me engano os dois são adjectivos. Então podemos usar os dois numa mesmo situação?

Eu ouço usar **de confiança** mais do que **confiável**.
Será que **de confiança** é mais comum?

Comment: Eu não sei se é uma regra, mas utilizaria *de confiança* para pessoas... e *confiável* para coisas... Por exemplo, Roberto é (uma pessoa) de confiança; esse sistema é confiável.

Comment: confiança é um subtantivo, e confiável é um adjetivo, só para começar.

Comment: @Peixoto Tua sugestão de regra teria muitas exceções ("Ela não é uma pessoa confiável." é uma frase comum), mas concordo que há algo nesse sentido. Soa mais apropriado, por exemplo, dizer "jornal confiável" que "jornal de confiança".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta curta:

- uma pessoa de confiança é uma pessoa em quem se confia, de quem não se espera traição. 
  "Preciso de alguém de confiança para trabalhar como caseiro.  Você conhece alguém?" Nesse exemplo, **podemos substituir "de confiança" por "confiável", sem mudança do significado**.

Contudo, existem usos idiomáticos para **"de confiança"**

- **um cargo de confiança** (uma ocupação, emprego, ou vaga, destinada a alguém de confiança) "Os cargos de confiança foram todos loteados no primeiro mês do mandato presidencial."
- **estar cheio de confiança** (estar seguro de si em relação a alguma coisa) "Ele mostrava-se cheio de confiança antes do início da competição"
- **ser digno de confiança** (merecer a confiança de outrem, mas também frequentemente usado na forma negativa) - "Você não é digno de confiança."
- **um voto de confiança** significa dar uma chance ou oportunidade a alguém em quem não se confia totalmente, geralmente por condutas prévias. - "Vou lhe dar um voto de confiança. Espero não me arrepender."
- **nível de confiança** (usado em estatística) "Nossa pesquisa tem um nível de confiança de 90%."
- **intervalo de confiança** (também usado em estatística) "Um intervalo de confiança de dois pontos percentuais para mais ou para menos."
- **indicadores de confiança** (usado em economia) "Os indicadores de confiança são todos favoráveis a novos investimentos."

Comment: Boa resposta, mas eu concordaria com o Peixoto que existem algumas diferenças quando se trata de objetos, por exemplo, "jornal confiável" me soa melhor que "jornal de confiança".

Answer (score 0):

A expressão "de confiança" é uma simplificação de "de **minha** confiança". Confiável refere-se a um caso geral.

Exemplo 1: "João é de confiança" quer dizer que EU confio em João
Exemplo 2: "João é confiável" quer dizer que todos, supostamente, confiam em João